# Isoperimetry / Concentration Inequality

Tags: probability, concentration-of-measure

I am currently working with Lipschitz functions $f: \{ 1, \dots , N \}^d \to \mathbf{R}$, and trying to obtain concentration bounds on $f(X)$ about it's mean, where $X$ is uniformly distributed on $\{ 1, \dots, N \}^d$. What is the best result in this setting?

Comment: Concentration of measure on hypercube is classical. See for example the book _Concentration Inequalities_.

Comment: See "An isoperimetric inequality on the discrete cube, and an elementary proof of the isoperimetric inequality in Gauss space" by Sergey Bobkov